# How to get the tableViewCell not to expand when swipe to delete

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, xcode7

I have my app set up so that I can add a cell to a ViewController where the cell appears in the tableView but when you click on the cell it expands to show more information. Here is the code...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomViewCell

    cell.clipsToBounds = true

    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if selectedIndexPath != nil {

        if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
            return 140
        } else {
            return 38
        }

    } else {
        return 38
    }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     // New
    switch selectedIndexPath {
    case nil:
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    default:
        if selectedIndexPath! == indexPath {
            selectedIndexPath = nil
        } else {
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        }
    }

    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

}
```

Everything works fine with the expanding and closing for the cell except that I configured the cell to swipe to delete but the cell just expands when I swipe to delete. Heres the code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {


    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete") { (action , indexPath ) -> Void in
        self.editing = false     
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let moc = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
        moc.deleteObject(self.events[indexPath.row])
        appDelegate.saveContext()             
        self.events.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    return [deleteAction]

}
```

[Before swipe to delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmYyW.png)

[After swipe to delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVsQU.png)

I dont want the the cell to expand like it is when I swipe to delete, Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think *you* may be the one who is expanding the cell. You are saying:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
        return 140
    }
}
```

Is that method being called during swipe to delete? Use debugging to find out. If it is, you'll need to rewrite that code so that, just in case you're in the middle of swipe to delete, you don't return 140.

Comment: I tried changing the 140 to 38, thinking that it wouldn't expand at all when I swiped but it did so I dont think that part of the code has an effect on it. It just returns to the normal size of the cell when it is swiped.